# How to sum data from two ranges if another range contains particular text

Tags: excel

I have two lists in excel and each of them contains a column of text + another column with points assigned to it. It looks something like that:

[image: foto 1]

As you can see both text and points can change. 
Additionally, I would like to add more lists to it (marked C, D, etc.)

On another sheet, I would like to prepare a summary that calculates the sum of the points assigned to text. I will a summary list with text entries:

[image: foto 2]

and I am looking for a formula which will give me sum of the points from all lists IF text from Summary cell matches any text from any list on previous sheet. The end results for these two lists will look like that:

[image: foto 3]

I tried some SUMIF variations but never got what I wanted. Can someone help me find correct formula?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take all the range, like that :

French Version = `=SOMME.SI($A$2:$C$5;A8;$B$2:$D$5)`

English Version = `=Sumif($A$2:$C$5,A8,$B$2:$D$5)`
[image]

Comment: I don't believe this will work with what they are asking. (for those who don't know `SOMME.SI()` is equaly to `SUMIF()`) On the "test" sheet i setup, i was not able to achieve close to what the `SUMPRODUCTS()` offers.

Comment: Hmm, i am still getting miscounts on my example table. Perhaps, i have something in wrong. I'll double check again.

I am pretty certain the english version of `Somme.si()` is `Sumif()` Can someone confirm?

Comment: Yes, ˋ=SOMME.SIˋ is the french ˋ=SUMIF`

Comment: Okay, found my mistake. My sorry for not believing you at first. I was still using semi-colons. I copied yours 100%, and forgot to change them to comma's instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general case.

Say `Sheet1` has many arbitrary data sets between column **A** and column **Z** like:
[image]

First put the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function Gsum(rng As Range, patrn As String) As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Gsum = 0

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Text = patrn Then
            Gsum = Gsum + r.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Put the data *abc* in `Sheet2` cell **B2** and in `Sheet2` cell **C2** enter:

```
=gsUM(Sheet1!A1:Z27,B2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is on sheet1 starting in A1 and the second sheet also starts in A1 on that sheet, put this in B2 and copy down:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:C,A2,Sheet1!B:D)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works. I would test it but I am away from my desk at the moment.

Note, that this formula should be placed on a separate worksheet (just in case).

`Sheet2!B2 = SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!$A$1:$AZ$100=Sheet2!$A1), OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$Z100,0,1))`

`Sheet1!A:AZ100 = The Range in which the data is contained`

`Sheet2!$A1 = The Cell that contains the criteria`

You could of course use Friendly names for the ranges if you wish.